# Is there a geometric interpretation for $\det(\nabla X)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, riemannian-geometry, determinant, geometric-interpretation

Let $X$ be a vector field on a Riemannain manifold $M$. Consider $\nabla X:TM \to TM$, where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $M$.

We know that $\operatorname{tr}(\nabla X)=\operatorname{div} X$ is the divergence of $X$, which has a geometric interpretation (it determines where the flow of $X$ is volume increasing or decreasing).

> I wonder: Does $\det(\nabla X)$ has a geometric interpretation as well?

I am particularly interested to know if there is any interpretation for $\nabla X$ being orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing (which corresponds to $\det(\nabla X)$ being everywhere positive or everywhere negative). Thus, even if there is no clear (quantitative) interpretation for the exact function $\det(\nabla X)$, I would like to know if there is any interpretation for it **having a definite sign**.

---

Note that $\nabla X:TM \to TM$ is (fiberwise) a self-map of a vector space, so its determinant is well-defined, even without any choice of orientation on $M$. (Though we may as well choose an orientation locally, or even fiberwise, so this does not really matter).

Comment: Wouldn't $\det (\nabla X)$ have to have constant sign on each connected component since it's a smooth map, hence continuous? EDIT: My bad, I see now your question is if the definite sign means anything. I don't know.

Comment: In fact, I am not sure that your statement that the sign would be constant is correct; this is only true if $\nabla X$ is everywhere invertible - then the determinant must have a definite sign. However, I am not sure that it cannot change its sign if we allow it to pass through zero. I guess that $\nabla X$ may be singular at some points.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I know no reason that $\nabla X$ has to be invertible.

Comment: Possibly useless comment. If you can foliate your manifold with geodesics, taking $X$ to be the unit tangent field of those geodesics will give you a case where $\det(\nabla X) = 0$ everywhere.